# How do I select a portion of the window using Love2d

Tags: lua, mouse, touch, love2d

I want to be able to divide the window of the game in, lets say, 3 places, and when the mouse (or touch) click one of those places, execute some code.

Do I have to make each portion a button-like object? or is there a way for me to use love.mouse.getPosition() and give different instructions to specifics range of coordinates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say you want to figure out if the user clicked/touched the left or right side of the window, and that your window is `800` units wide. Then the code is very simple; in your click handler (typically [`love.mousepressed()`](https://love2d.org/wiki/love.mousepressed)) check if the `x` position of the mouse is less than or greater than half that, `400`:

```
function love.mousepressed(x, y, button, istouch)
   if button == 1 then
      if x < 400 then
          -- left side clicked
      else
          -- right side clicked
      end
   end
end
```

But if you're doing anything more complex than that, like a GUI, this quickly becomes unmaintainable. Think about adjusting those GUI elements, adding new buttons, resizing them, changing the layout, and calculating those magic numbers... yuck! Then it's best to look at a proper GUI library, or code your own. But under the hood the library will be doing the same thing - checking the mouse press against coordinate numbers.